# NullPointerException when calling mAdView.loadAd

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, admob

I added Google ads to my app. And they work fine on my OnePlus One device. I don't understand, why it did not work. I even added check to see, if the object is null before loading it. When I tested it on a Nexus 7 Virtual device. It gave me this exception:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{koemdzhiev.com.eggyegg/koemdzhiev.com.eggyegg.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at koemdzhiev.com.eggyegg.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
```

This is my code in main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Google ads
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    if(adRequest != null) {
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

Comment: are you sure mAdView is not null? you are checking if the request is not null but mAdView has no safety check and seems the only reason for causing a null pointer exception

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for your comment! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, it was quite simple. Instead of checking if adRequest is null I checked mAdView like this:

```
 AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    if(mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```